# If no results exist in mysql table echo something else?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone please help me, i am trying to show different images based on the records i have for each user in my table 'permissions'. i am using .

if the records dont exist in the table i want to include a different file path i.e.

At the moment it brings up results if the users permission is set to 1 or 0 but i want to make it so that if no results are found in the table it shows something as a default.

code:

```
<?php if (logged_in()) { 
    $account_perms = account_perms();
    while ($perms = mysql_fetch_array($account_perms)) {
    if ($perms['privellages'] == '1')  {
        if ( mysql_num_rows( $perms ) > 0 )
              include('includes/mod_profile/mod_photos/private.php'); 
    } 
    }
    $account_perms = account_perms();
    while ($perms = mysql_fetch_array($account_perms)) {
    if ($perms['privellages'] == '0')  {
     include('includes/mod_profile/mod_photos/private2.php'); 
    } 
    } 
    $account_perms = account_perms();
    while ($perms = mysql_fetch_array($account_perms)) {
      if($perms->num_rows > 0) {
         include('includes/mod_profile/mod_photos/private2.php'); 
      } 
    } 
} ?>
```

Comment: Could you do with a little bit less ?> <?php It will improve readability. It's all PHP so why do it like that anyway?

Comment: `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use `PDO` or `mysqli` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?
if (logged_in()) {

    $account_perms = account_perms();
    if (mysql_num_rows($account_perms)) {
        while ($perms = mysql_fetch_array($account_perms)) {
            if ($perms['privellages'] == '1') {
                if (mysql_num_rows($perms) > 0)

                    include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_photos/private.php');
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No records';
    }

    $account_perms = account_perms();
    if (mysql_num_rows($account_perms)) {
        while ($perms = mysql_fetch_array($account_perms)) {
            if ($perms['privellages'] == '0') {

                include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_photos/private2.php');

            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No records';
    }

    $account_perms = account_perms();
    if (mysql_num_rows($account_perms)) {
        while ($perms = mysql_fetch_array($account_perms)) {
            if ($perms -> num_rows > 0) {

                include ('includes/mod_profile/mod_photos/private2.php');

            }
        }
    } else {
        echo 'No records';
    }
}
?>
```